# Can WebM contain FLAC audio?

Tags: webm, flac

So can a WebM video contain FLAC audio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it has been [proposed/discussed](https://groups.google.com/a/webmproject.org/forum/#!topic/webm-discuss/Qv1TxxsrzHQ), but currently [webm](http://www.webmproject.org/) only [support Vorbis](http://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/) for audio.

From the Demuxer and Muxer Guidelines:

> Audio codec SHOULD be Vorbis.
>   [...]

More details can be found [here](http://www.webmproject.org/).

Comment: Ok so VP9 video can be lossless as shown [here](http://www.webmproject.org/docs/encoder-parameters/#vp9-specific-options).
Can Vorbis be lossless? According to the [faq](http://www.webmproject.org/about/faq/), audio can also be Opus. So can Opus be lossless? Or is there any other way to get lossless audio in a WebM?

Comment: @Brandon Opus seem to supported with vp9. [Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_%28audio_format%29) is lossy though (as is Vorbis).

Comment: @Brandon you can embed Flac with Matroska (webm is based on this container), but I am unsure of the support of it.

Comment: Ok, I'll just use Matroska for now then